# Back/Forward Swipe Gesture in WebViews

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, gesture

I've looked at another post here on Stack Overflow concerning the back gesture, but mine is a little different.

How can I implement the swipe gesture to go 'Back' and 'Forward', to have an effect on the WebView the cursor is over? For example, if there are more than one, the gesture goes to and affects the appropriate view.

I suppose it would be the following code, but I do not know how to get the gesture methods to work:

```
- (void) backGesture {
    [(WebView *)self.theWebView goBack];
}

- (void) forwardGesture {
    [(WebView *)self.theWebView goForward];
}
```

Where 'theWebView' is the WebView the cursor is hovered over.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You may want to try using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. You can find out the coordinates of the touches when the target method is invoked.

Comment: As I discovered below, it's actually an OS/X question, so I have added that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could add a category to webView with a swipeWithEvent methd, so that each view handles its own swipe (the three-finger variety; the two-finger scrolling is translated into mouse actions for the webview).

WebView+addSwipe.h:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface WebView (addSwipe)
@end
```

WebView+addSwipe.m:

```
#import "WebView+addSwipe.h"

@implementation WebView (addSwipe)

- (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    CGFloat deltaX = [event deltaX];
    if (deltaX > 0) {
        NSLog(@"goForward %@ ", self);
        [self goForward];
    } else if (deltaX < 0) {
        NSLog(@"goBack%@ ", self);
        [self goBack];
    }
}

@end
```

And, if you WERE on iOS, attach two UISwipeGestureRecognizers to each view; one for each direction with separate actions:

```
-(void) backGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [sender.view goBack];
}

-(void) forwardGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender)
    [sender.view goForward];
}
```

with your viewController as the target.  Each gesture action will be handed a sender, so sender.view will tell you which view had the swipe in it.

Note that "Three Finger Swipe to Navigate" must be on in Trackpad control panel on the system your program is running on.

Comment: ok so the sender is what I will use to identify the WebView, however your solution is for iOS, I'm developing for Mac :), any ideas?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Does the revised version help?

Comment: will take a look at it soon, it's late here ;) Thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand how I define [event locationInWindow], any ideas?

Comment: Well, that gets back to the base (single view) case),  e.g. Apple's doc on "Handling Trackpad Events".  If you implement - (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event, then "event" is defined for you, and it has a locationInWindow method.   I've done this in the code above.

Comment: your code seems like it should work, I must be doing something wrong but it just doesn't do anything, even a basic NSLog() inside that method doesn't fire when I do a back/forward gesture.

Comment: Have you set acceptsFirstResponder:YES and acceptsTouchEvents:YES

Comment: i've never seen those options before! where can I find them? you've taught me so much lol thanks :)

Comment: Well, decided to actually try it, and discovered that those aren't necessary, but that the swipes don't seem to be handed to the viewController at all, so I changed over to a Webview category.  See above revised version.  Note that Three Finger Swipe to Navigate must be on in Trackpad control panel.

Comment: Glad to help; it came out quite simple and useful.  I assume it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom gestures, but you've got to implement touches began, touches moved and touches ended. The best way would be to have a CGPoint named startPoint and a second CGPoint named endPoint. On touches began, you store the location of the touch into startPoint. In touches ended, you store the end point in endPoint. To see if it was a back swipe, compare the x values of the two points! Here's a link on receiving touches: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-detecting-touches/
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

For two finger swipes, check out https://github.com/Kapeli/SwipableWebView